# Which of following pictures does not represent real function with one variable y=f(x)?

Tags: functions

I have some pictures and have to select those who does not represent real function with one variable y=f(x).

I think that these are #4 and #5(if #1 is upper left corner), because there can hardly be more images than one for actual x.

Am I right?

[image]

Comment: (ii)${}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: yea, it looks like sign, but now I see its kinda shifted

Comment: Can anybody confirm me I am right if I say that 2,4,5 do not represent real function with one variable and every other does?

Comment: You are correct that $4$ and $5$ fail.  And your reason that for some $x$ values there are more than one image value.  ... But $4$ and $5$ are not the only ones that fail or that fail for that reason.

Comment: So 2,4 and 5 fail and every other is allright?

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't include a image where some of the $x$ have *no* image. That would fail to be a *real* function as not every element in the domain (*all* real numbers) would have an image.

Comment: Would you be so kind and aswer me, please? :)

Comment: But yes, 1, 3, and 6 (assuming they extend off the picture and don't just ... end) are valid functions.  (I'm also surprised they didn't include so one-to-one valid functions to trip up students who might, incorrectly think functions had to pass a "horizontal line test" [which functions *don't* have to pass.... 1,3, and 6 fail the (irrelevant) "horizontal line test" (and only the non-function 4 passes).  (The "*vertical* line test" *is* required for functions and $2,4,5$ are all not functions because they fail)])

Comment: It passed, thanks a lot, sir(or madam). :)